# How to I identify the device on which android tests are currently running?

Tags: android, gradle

I have multiple devices connected and I run the gradle command 'connectedCheck' which runs tests on multiple devices.

ConnectedCheck executes tests on all the devices in an order. I want to get the serial number of the device the tests are currently being run on.

Does android provide a way to do that?

Comment: yea you can get like GT-19300

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution! In fact there wasn't a problem in the first place.

**Issue:** Gradle android plugin's task to run tests is 'connectedCheck'. It executes tests on how many ever android devices connected to a host. Now when I @Ignore a test it will be ignored on all those devices where as I wanted to do that only for the failing device/devices

**Solution:** Add a custom jUnit annotation that takes an array of String values for Device serial IDs. Write a custom test runner by extending [BlockJUnit4ClassRunner](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.html) override [runChild](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.html#runChild(org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod,%20org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier)) to check if Build.Device is same as the one provided in the annotation if a method is annotated.

If it is [fireTestIgnored](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/notification/RunNotifier.html#fireTestIgnored(org.junit.runner.Description)) to ignore so that it will be skipped only for the device you specified in the annotation.